# Unset or delete a cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to remove some cookies that I set at a specific point in my code but they are not being fully unset or deleted.

I had just been unsetting them and then after a bit of research into this issue I seen a lot of people were setting the cookie to blank with a negative time expiry like so:

```
unset($_COOKIE["lifting365_last_name"]);
setcookie("lifting365_customer_id", "", time()-3600);
```

When I do this and then `var_dump($_COOKIE);` the cookies I set are not being dumped on screen. They seem to not exist any more.

However, if I navigate to another page, the cookies are back to what I had set them previously.

Is there a way to *fully* delete my cookies?

Comment: I would suspect the cookies have a `$path` parameter set. You need to do the expiring `setcookie` with the exact same `$path` and `$domain` value from the original call.

Comment: _However, if I navigate to another page_ Could it be that that other page has recreated the cookie because that page uses that cookie

Comment: You will have to show us how you set these cookies before we can do much more than play 20 guesses. @ceejayoz may be right or my previous comment may be right, but without code we will never know

Comment: Are you on a localhost? Cookies act very differently on localhost environments.

Comment: Another possible cause: You use `setcookie()` after the output already has been started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Unset command just removes the data from the super global $_COOKIES at runtime, the actual cookie is stored on the users computer and is passed in the request which PHP then populates into the COOKIES global.

In order to remove a cookie the PATH part of the cookie needs to be the same as the current path you are in or set to '/' to be available across the entire domain.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "Some Data", 0, '/');
```

This makes it available across the domain and will expire at the end of the session or closing of the browser.

Then to delete:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "", time()-3600, '/');
```

I would also check the time on both the server and client are correct for testing.